# ¿Cómo combinar la investigación de varios cuadros de búsqueda?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una base de datos con muchos campos :

```
ROLE NOM                PRENOM   SEXE   GRADE   N° INC  N° BSN          Date de naissance   Ages    LIEU NAISSANCE  ADRESSE DE REPLI        C.P     VILLE           N° de Tel
CA   Mitaux-Maurouard   Guy      M      CCH     80 000  10.00.31642     03/07/38            28      LA ROCHELLE     Séminaire de Castille   83210   SOLLIES-VILLE   06 13 00 00 00
FP   Cho                Gwang-Je M      LC      85 252  10.25.25456     05/03/53            25      SEOUL           Kunsan Air Base         12424   Kunsan     0524289324
...
```

y me gustaría hacer una interfaz de búsqueda que permita hacer una investigación muy fina.

[image: photo]]

Sé que gracias a Alvaro CC cómo hacer para dos columnas con un UserForm :

```
Option Compare Text

' Método que se activa al escribir en el campo del primer nombre
 Private Sub name_reservist_Change()
    ListBoxResults.Clear
    If name_reservist <> "" Then searchresults
End Sub

' Método que se dispara al escribir en el campo de apellidos
Private Sub surname_reservist_Change() 'www.blog-excel.com/creer-un-champ-de-recherche-vba
    ListBoxResults.Clear
    If surname_reservist <> "" Then searchresults
End Sub

' Método que agrega resultados de búsqueda
 Sub searchresults()
    ListBoxResults.Clear
    For ligne = 2 To Sheets("RECAP").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
        If Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4) Like "*" & name_reservist & "*" And Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) Like "*" & surname_reservist & "*" Then
            ListBoxResults.AddItem Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) & " " & Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

¿Pero cómo hacer tantos campos sin que se vuelvan ilegibles?

Parece que puedo utilisar el metodo "autofilter", o pasar el rango a un array y recorrerlo , pasar el rango a un recordset y hacer una sql. Sin embargo nadie utilizo estos metodos.

Answer (score 0):

Algo de este estilo te valdria?

```
 Sub searchresults()
    ListBoxResults.Clear
    For ligne = 2 To Sheets("RECAP").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row

    cond1=Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4) Like "*" & name_reservist & "*"
    cond2=Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) Like "*" & surname_reservist & "*" 
    cond100=Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) Like "*" & surname_reservist & "*" 

     if cond1  And cond2 and cond100 Then _ 
        ListBoxResults.AddItem Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne,3) & " " & Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4)

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Si si Me parece que es una buena solución. Dejo la pregunta abierta hasta esta noche si alguien alguna vez encuentra otra solución. Cuando vemos que un TextBox o ComboBox cambian, lo hacemos con `TextBox_change()` o `ComboBox_change()`. ¿Sabes cómo monitorear un conjunto de estos?

Comment: Una forma de hacerlo es redirigir todos los eventos a un procedimiento (del tipo "searchresults"), si pasamos como argumento el nombre del control  (`Application.Caller`)  podemos  implementar la logica de todos los eventos dentro de searchresult ,  no se si queda claro

Comment: Si esta claro pero no conozco el nombre del control de todas la TextBox y ComboBox de mi UserForm. Ni siquiera sabía que podría existir.

Comment: bueno , en algun momento sabras todos tus campos a controlar .Respecto a si se puede interceptar  un grupo de eventos ,la verdad es que yo no sabria hacerlo